# How do I get Word 2007 to number headings correctly?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I want headings to be like:

**1 Heading 1

1.1 Heading 2

1.1.1 Heading 3

1.1.1.1 Heading 4**

And every time I use a heading I want it to auto-number, but from style formatting I don't seem able to access the advanced numbering options.

I don't even know why I have to mess about with styles for this. Numbering on headings should be so common it's an easy on/off option!

Comment: Can you give us some more information please?

Answer (score 2):

From the Home menu, in the Paragraph division, look for the tooltip that says "Multilevel List." It's third from the left on the top row.

[image]

Click the down-arrow, then look for the top right square in the popup.

[image]

This should do it.